# mysql get records between two dates with meta value

Tags: mysql, date

i am firing Sql Query to get records between two dates in wp_postmeta table.

i am running following query :

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM `wp_postmeta`
  WHERE`meta_key` LIKE 'date'
  AND `meta_value` >= '02/01/2015' 
  AND `meta_value` <  '20/10/2015'
```

this query should return the result which has mata value between  02/01/2015 to 20/10/2015

unfortunately it returns 01/01/2014 and all other records of 2014.

it returns wrong results. it shows the 2014 dates  in result.

what am i doing wrong?   i want to get record between 2 dates by meta_value

Comment: What type is `meta_value` is it `varchar` or `date`?

Comment: What is data type of `meta_value` in your database?

Comment: Are those dates actually stored as datetime types? This result makes sense if they were stored as text.

Comment: `meta_value` is longtext.

Comment: In essence, while 1001 is larger than 123, '1001' comes before '123' alphabetically speaking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert your varchar date into a real date. Then use either `between`

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM `wp_postmeta`
  WHERE`meta_key` = 'date'
  AND STR_TO_DATE(meta_value, '%d/%m/%Y') between '2015-01-02' AND '2015-10-19'
```

or `<` and `>`

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM `wp_postmeta`
  WHERE`meta_key` = 'date'
  AND STR_TO_DATE(meta_value, '%d/%m/%Y') >= '2015-01-02' 
  AND STR_TO_DATE(meta_value, '%d/%m/%Y') < '2015-10-20'
```

Comment: Between clause includes `2015-10-20` and OP excluded `2015-10-20`

Comment: what if date format is 10/12/2014? i mean slash instead of dash?

Comment: @JackTorris: Date is stored always the same internally. You can only change the formatting when selecting. `YYYY-MM-DD` is a default date format that works always.

Comment: there is one issue. if i run following query then it doesn't return anything      SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE`meta_key` = 'date' AND STR_TO_DATE(meta_value, '%m/%d/%Y') between '02/04/2015' AND '10/21/2015'

Comment: @JackTorris: Because `02/04/2015` is not a valid date format.